# Microsoft VSTS doesn't build Android project - JavaMaximumHeapSize - works on local machine

Tags: java, android, xamarin, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using private build agent for my builds. (This works on VS Appcenter, if you use their machine but it costs and build is slow, or if you use Hosted VS2017 from VSTS, anyway I am using my own private agent for all VSTS builds, speed and cost).

Error is complaining about JavaMaximumHeapSize.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2188,3):
>   Error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the
>   value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while
>   executing 'java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\lib\dx.jar" --dex
>   --no-strict --multi-dex --main-dex-list=obj\Release\multidex.keep --output obj\Release\android\bin D:\agent_work\9\s\src\Yo.MobileApp.Android\obj\Release\android\bin\classes.zip
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\mono.android.jar"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar"
>   obj\Release\lp\1\jl\formsviewgroup.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\31\jl\arch-core-common.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\32\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\34\jl\bin\classes.jar ob... C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2188,3):
>   error XA5213: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the
>   value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while
>   executing 'java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\lib\dx.jar" --dex
>   --no-strict --multi-dex --main-dex-list=obj\Release\multidex.keep --output obj\Release\android\bin D:\agent_work\9\s\src\Yo.MobileApp.Android\obj\Release\android\bin\classes.zip
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\mono.android.jar"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar"
>   obj\Release\lp\1\jl\formsviewgroup.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\31\jl\arch-core-common.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\32\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\33\jl\bin\classes.jar
>   obj\Release\lp\34\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Release...

- I already increased JavaMaximumHeapSize to 1G inside of Application
  Manifest.
- I already set JDK to 8 and selected x86 architecture:
  [image]

If I put x64 arch and JDK 8 or same for JDK9 I get error:

> 2018-04-14T10:32:54.9545073Z ##[error]Cannot bind argument to
>   parameter 'KeyName' because it is an empty string.

Comment: "I already increased JavaMaximumHeapSize to 1G inside of Application Manifest", Did you manually edit the manifest or did you used the properties editor of the .csproj?

Comment: I fixed it I’ll write answer later

Comment: Use a 64 bit version of the JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK8 and x64 solves teh problem.

Comment: you can accept your own answers. please mark this as accepted answer if this worked.This thread still shows up as "unanswered"